# How to combine ground truth labels (multiple masking images) of Data Science Bowl 2018 into single image?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

[Ground truth masking of a single image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPgSD.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IDtrn contains folders names that are unique
Each foler have 2 subfolders:

- Images
- Masks

This code is working for me:

```
for i in IDtrn:
Ytrain = []
temp = glob.glob(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, i, 'masks', '*'))
mask = np.zeros((256, 256))
for j in temp:
    mask_ = cv2.imread(j, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    mask_ = cv2.resize(mask_, (256, 256))
    mask = np.maximum(mask, mask_)
    Ytrain = Ytrain + [mask]
Ytrain = np.asarray(Ytrain)
img = Ytrain[len(temp)-1].astype(np.uint8)
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.convert('RGB')
img.save(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, i, 'masks', 'combined_mask.png'))
```